# How do I control weeds with dogs present?

Tags: dogs, safety, eating

Is it safe to use round-up on my weeds and / or weed and feed in my yard, although the dogs go out in the yard?  My concern is if they eat the weeds, they would be poisoned, or they could possibly even be harmed by walking in it.  If both these products are harmful, do you have any suggestions for weed control that is safe for pets?

Comment: They are only weeds if you don't want them.  Decide you like dandelions in your yard and you will not have any weeds.

Comment: P.S. dandelions are a healthy addition to any diet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a herbicide such as Round-Up on your lawn, as well as insecticides, are not only harmful to the environment in general, but especially harmful to dogs and other pets using the lawn.

Pets and pesticide use fact sheet:  http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/petspest.pdf

> Animals can be exposed to pesticides when they breathe in the product, absorb it through their skin, or ingest the product.
>   Your pet’s risk of developing a health problem depends on how much pesticide your pet is exposed to and the toxicity of
>   the pesticide to that specific type of animal. Pet owners can minimize the chance of their pet having a problem by following
>   label directions, selecting lower toxicity pesticides, and minimizing the amount of exposure their pet has to the pesticide
>   during and after the application.

A new study also found that these chemicals can be passed on [from dogs to their owners](http://www.mnn.com/family/pets/stories/how-lawn-chemicals-and-herbicides-affect-dogs) :

> "Gastrointestinal upset is the most common sign seen when ingestion of fertilizer and herbicide occurs," she says. "However, if large amounts or concentrated products are ingested, veterinary intervention may be necessary. In addition, very young, very old, and debilitated animals may be more sensitive to exposures."

There are other, safer ways to control weeds and other problems in your lawn, such as organic mixtures (concentrated vinegar and salt solution) as well as a spot-spray weed killer, so it does not affect your whole lawn and will be overall healthier for you and your pet.

http://www.lawnsmith.co.uk/lawn-care-advice/lawn-faqs/kids-pets-wildlife-safety/

[image]